# UMP test for $\theta$ belonging to 3 different regions

Tags: hypothesis-testing

> Let $X_{1} ,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a $N(\theta, 1)$ distribution. Let $0 < \alpha < 1$ and $\theta_{1} < \theta_{2} < \theta_{3} < \theta_{4}$. Consider testing the following set of hypotheses: $H_{0} : \theta \leq \theta_{1}$ or $\theta_{2} < \theta < \theta_{3}$ or $\theta \geq \theta_{4}$ vs $H_{1} : \theta_{1} < \theta < \theta_{2}$ or $\theta_{3} < \theta < \theta_{4}$. Does there exist a level-alpha UMP test for the above? If yes, derive the test. If not, explain why not.

I think the UMP test wouldn't exist because here there are 5 regions and I'm not sure how to deal with them other than dealing them separately like if test $H_{0} : \theta \leq \theta_{1}$ against $H_{1} : \theta > \theta_{1}$, there'd be an UMP test based on the MLR. And the power curve for that will be strictly increasing, so it'll have better power than whatever this UMP test function is (if it exists) since it has to maintain level alpha at all the points $\theta_1,...,\theta_4$. Can someone please check this?

Comment: It is misleading to characterize this as "three different regions:" as always, $H_0$ is *one* subset of the parameter space and $H_A$ is its complement.  Yes, there is a natural (and useful) topology on the parameter space and in this topology both hypotheses are *disconnected.*  Think of ways to exploit that situation by applying the definition of a UMP test.

Comment: can't get anything, can you give a clue? @whuber

Comment: Sketch the regions (in the line) corresponding to the hypotheses.

Comment: I sketched them, but it didn't give me a clue. Is the powerfunction continuous  for an UMP test?